# Stop calling opencart 1.5 controller function from outsite of opencart using cookie

Tags: cookies, opencart

I am using opencart 1.5 version. I have a function in controller & want to call in checkout. That's working fine. But the issue was someone like hacker call this function outside from opencart and store some unwanted fake data in my database.
so i want to stop call that controller function outside from opencart. It should be called only from opencart checkout like ajax call. Call that function outside (external client) using cookie is strictly prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to prevent **CSRF** attack on the controller method.
You can try a *Token validation* in the Controller method. Set the token to some value & then check in controller if that's the same token. If it matches execute the Business logic or else do nothing (or report it).

Implement this on Checkout Module.

```
     $token= md5(uniqid());
     $_SESSION['csrf_token']= $token;
```

Now match the Token in SESSION & One coming in the Request to Controller Method:

```
     $token = $this->session->data['csrf_token'];
     unset($this->session->data['csrf_token']);
     if ($token && $this->request->post['token'] == $token) {
       // Apply your Business Logic
     } else {
       // Log a potential CSRF attack.
     }
```

There are more complex ways to do the same, but i think this should be helpful.

Comment: When i am sending token from html from in hidden mode then hacker will inspect & see the token. then he will copy this token and again post it from outside. How can i protect?

Comment: @ShojibFlamon To add more security you can verify the `Referrer` if that's the same domain as your Opencart store then only do something or else ignore it.
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`